# Set value to variable depending on input, StringProperty kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have an issue with Kivy StringProperty variable when i try to update the value based on inputs.

to make it a bit simple so I can understand too (I'm a bit new to this).

```
TextTime1 = StringProperty()
TextTime2 = StringProperty()
x = 2

TextTime+x = "TEST"
```

How can I get that to work?

I have tried

```
TextTime1 = StringProperty()
TextTime2 = StringProperty()
TextTimes = [TextTime1, TextTime2]
x = 2

TextTimes[x-1] = "TEST"
```

Does not work.
Only thing that works is:

```
TextTime1 = StringProperty()
TextTime2 = StringProperty()

TextTime2 = "TEST"
```

How can I get the more "dynamic" way to work?

Comment: Don’t you need to call ‘set()’ to set a new value? Perhaps you need: TextTimes[x-1].set( "TEST")

Comment: Nop, even that did now work. Tried a for x in TextTimes: x = "TEST", that set the list item to TEST i beleve. And if I did x.set("TEST") it just didnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you are trying to replace the last value in a list?

You could probably make it work like this

```py
TextTime1 = StringProperty()
TextTime2 = StringProperty()

TextTimes = [TextTime1, TextTime2]

TextTimes.pop()
TextTimes.append("TEST")
```

Comment: No, I want to add value to the variables in the list. Example: TextTime1 = "TEST".

Comment: Then why not change the value of the variable. Doesn't matter if it's part of a list or not

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do. But if I have 50 of these TextTimes, connected to differend inputs. I need some sort of code to handle that. I cant do: if x == 2: TextTime2 = "TEST"...

Comment: You are telling that list doesn't work. What exactly doesn't work? Maybe you forgot to connect your inputs with the variables that are in the list instead of first ones?

Comment: Why don't you try using a dictionary?

`TextTimes = {"TextTimes1": "TEST1", "TextTimes2": "TEST2"}`

Comment: But would that dict values really connect to the real variable?

Comment: Well no but they are connected to the dictionary index, so the TextTimes1 is equal to TextTimes["TextTimes1"]

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of variables is a bit shallow. For instance, TextTimes+x="TEST" is not valid because you aren't saying TextTimes2 = "TEST", you are saying TextTimes + 2 = "TEST".

Your second method isn't entirely wrong.

```
TextTimes[x-1] = "TEST"
# = TextTimes[1] = "TEST"
# = TextTimes2 = "TEST" since TextTimes2 is the assigned index for that variable
# in your TextTimes list.
# However the correct list should be
TextTimes = [self.TextTimes1,self.TextTimes2] # if they are properties of an object
```

Example:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    TextTimes1 = StringProperty()
    TextTimes2 = StringProperty()
    #TextTimes = [self.TextTimes1,self.TextTimes2]
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.TextTimes = [self.TextTimes1,self.TextTimes2]


    def some_function(self):
        x = 2
        self.TextTimes[x-1]="TEST" #This should change the value for TextTimes2 to "TEST"
```

Comment: Ok I will try it again.

Comment: Nop, cant get it to work like that.
Only thing that works is if I set the string to the variable directly e.g. self.TextTime2 = "TEST"

Comment: You're right. I see the problem in my logic is because when i do self.texttimes[i] im just referencing the value of the property.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you'd need something like this for. I've never found that I've had to use it for all my desktop developing so far.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can see this work with my limited knowlage about this would be.

```
if x == 2:
    TextTime2 = "TEST"
```

That just feels wrong and alot of code if I have > 50 of them...